# NSPredicate to test for NULL, and blank strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have an `NSArray` and need to filter out any strings that are null or rather, have ' ' (empty string). How do I do that? I have tried doing:

```
NSPredicate *predicateName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name!=nil)"];
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Or maybe it does but there are different kinds of null...

Answer (score 153, accepted):

If you don't use Core Data, you could do:

```
NSPredicate *predicateName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name.length > 0"];
```

If the string is empty, this will fail (because `0 == 0`).  Similarly, if `name` is `nil`, it will also fail, because `[nil length] == 0`.

Comment: So then what is the solution mate? This one actually seems to work for me where as the first answer doesn't. If string is empty, then wont length = 0? it isn't null

Comment: @Doron the solution is to use the predicate I suggested.

Comment: Sorry mate but i still get (null) in certain fields. So not sure what you meant by your comment after the code. == 0 so you are saying you are getting a value of 0, so all i need to test is > 0. to be 1. Because i am still getting (null)

Comment: 2011-09-11 21:24:14.282 iKosher[89194:13703] Brand**COLES
2011-09-11 21:24:14.282 iKosher[89194:13703] Brand**WAITROSE
2011-09-11 21:24:14.283 iKosher[89194:13703] Brand**(null)
2011-09-11 21:24:14.283 iKosher[89194:13703] Brand**(null)
2011-09-11 21:24:14.283 iKosher[89194:13703] Brand**VILLAGE GREEN

Comment: !!! **Beware with CoreData** length is not supported, and worse will fail silently returning strange results. CoreData translates the predicate `name.length > 1` to sqlite in `name > 1`... While it should be `length(name) > 1`

Comment: @VincentG interesting. sounds like a bug. have you filed one? https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: @Dave DeLong, just did, searched a while in `CoreData`/`NSPredicate` documentation, no mention at all of `length`. Makes sense that it works on object arrays thanks to `keypath` evaluation. But on sqlite, I presume that is not so obvious... Maybe a missing feature, but anyway, that should raise an error in that case.

Comment: So does this answer not work then? I'm having a similar problem

Comment: I just used the suggested technique (i.e. name.length > 0) in a core-data NSPredicate and it worked as expected so if it was broken then it is fixed now (iOS 6.1 on Simulator).

Comment: I noticed that when `name`.length > 0 but `name` the first character is a whitespace -> it will not return it

Comment: Got tricked once again today by this one with CoreData... damn it. Kinda funny that I found my own previous comment looking for this :)

Comment: @VincentG how about [using a regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14148659/375300) for a Core Data predicate (as long as it is performant enough)?

Comment: what about objects that aren't strings?

Comment: @VincentG - then what is the solution for CoreData?

Comment: This is very dangerous. @VincentG is right. I have a string with a leading '/' character which did not work with `.length`. I had to use the `name!=nil AND name!=''` like @josema.vitaminew posted

Answer (score 90):

I think this should work:

```
NSPredicate *predicateName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name!=nil AND name!=''"];
```

Comment: This works find for Realm database predicates as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

```
 NSPredicate *predicateName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name!=NULL"];
```

Answer (score 7):

This predicate worked for me:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K== nil) OR %K.length == 0", @"imageUrl", @"imageUrl"]
```