# How to check NSString type DB object is null?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, iphonecoredatarecipes

I wanted to fetch only those users who do not have ***null*** **lastname** which of NSString type.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"USER" inManagedObjectContext:dbHandler.managedObjectContext];

    NSMutableArray * predicateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSPredicate * predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id = %@",abc];
    [predicateArray addObject:predicate1];

    NSPredicate * predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastname != %@",nil];
    [predicateArray addObject:predicate2];

    NSCompoundPredicate * resultantPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateArray];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:resultantPredicate];

    NSError *fetchError = nil;

    NSArray *result = [dbHandler.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&fetchError];
```

Predicate2 is not working for some reason.After applying it no object is returned even if DB contains some Non-Null string values of lastname. Please tell what is wrong in the code or is there any way to fetch not-null string ONLY from core data .

Comment: Place the word `nil` directly in the format string.

Comment: nil, Nil, Null didnt worked!

Comment: @Divjyot - try the duplicate answer once , if duplicate answer does not resolved ur issue ping here, I reopen ur question again

Comment: will try NSPredicate *predicateName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name!=nil AND name!=' ' "];

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik That last didn't work

Comment: the **length > 0**  is worked or not

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik NO, the original answer had it already mentioned that it will NOT work for CORE DATA.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use method which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7369576/2185873).

Just replace

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastname != %@",nil]
```

with

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastname.length > 0"]
```

**UPDATE**

This predicates will return nil objects

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastname = NULL"];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastname = NIL"];
```

This predicate will return empty strings

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastname = ''"];
```

Comment: .length property is not available in core data and If the string is empty, this will fail (because 0 == 0). Similarly, if name is nil, it will also fail, because [nil length] == 0. as wriiten in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369390/nspredicate-to-test-for-null-and-blank-strings

Comment: So, when user has empty string as 'lastname' will be different case if user has 'nil' as lastname, right?

Comment: nil can show itself as empty lastname but an empty string @" " is not equal to nil.

Comment: @Divjyot, I know :) But it depend from your logic. Is logic the same for both cases or not…

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108824/discussion-between-divjyot-and-che).