# Realm filter empty objects in a list of Results

Tags: swift, realm

I want to filter a list of realm results if the `id` is nil or empty.

Here is a demo list of results :

```
{
  "id":"1"
  "name": "first"
},
{
  "id":"2"
  "name": "second"
},
{
  "id":"3"
  "name": "third"
},
{
  "id":"" //here it can be empty
  "name": ""
},
{
  "id": nil // here it can be nil
  "name": nil
}
```

I try to filter using the id like this but it crash :

```
 lazy var declarations: Results<Declaration> = {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        return self.realm.objects(Declaration.self).filter("id == " "")
    }()
```

Here is the model :

```
import RealmSwift

public final class Declaration: Object {
    dynamic var id: String = ""
    dynamic var name: String = ""

    override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`.filter("id == " "")` would definitely crash because you haven't escaped those quotes. It could need `.filter("id == \"\"")`, but just using single quotes would be better.

Since Realm queries conform to `NSPredicate`, copying the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369390/nspredicate-to-test-for-null-and-blank-strings), if you want to simply check if a Realm property isn't empty or nil, you should just be able to query using

```
lazy var declarations: Results<Declaration> = {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    return self.realm.objects(Declaration.self).filter("id != nil AND id != ''")
}()
```