# How do you retrieve the last month's entries from core data

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios5, predicates

how do I ask core data to fetch me the last 30 elements entered or alternatively the elements entered within a month of today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch a certain number of records, use qualification like `[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:30]` in combination with NSPredicate instance you desired.

To retrieve elements within a range of time, you need first calculate the beginning and the end NSDate instances of the period you want, then code your predicate instance like:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
            @"(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)", startDate, endDate];
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644621/nspredicate-for-an-nsmanagedobjects-string-attributes-length) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965331/nspredicate-filtering-objects-by-day-of-nsdate-property).

Comment: Thanks I'll probably use the second option but wouldn't the [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:30] retrieve the first 30 and not the last 30?

Comment: ok I can probably sort in descending order and then do the setFetchLimit

Comment: Yeah. Just as you've figured out.