# How to create a Predicate macro that filters a PersistentModel according to the number of characters contained in a String property?

Tags: swift, swift-data

Let's create a `PersistentModel` called `Item`.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model final class Item {
    var text: String
    
    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
}
```

When I try to filter items according to the number of characters in the `text` property, the predicate doesn't seem to work.

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query(filter: #Predicate { $0.text.count == 4 }) private var items: [Item]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            // items is empty :(
            List(items) { /* ... */ }
        }
        .onAppear {
            try! modelContext.delete(model: Item.self)
            let newItems = [
                Item(text: "foo"),
                Item(text: "bar"),
                Item(text: "baz"),
                Item(text: "qux"),
                Item(text: "quux"),
                Item(text: "corge")
            ]
            for item in newItems { modelContext.insert(item) }
            try! modelContext.save()
        }
    }
}
```

Tested under **Xcode 15 beta 4**.

Comment: [It doesn't support that (yet).](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/predicate)

Comment: @Sweeper Damn… Thanks for the clarification. What's the point of Query if it doesn't support such basic predicates? Do you think this feature will be added in the final version of Xcode 15, or will we have to wait for a major SwiftData update?

Comment: [Even with CoreData/`NSPredicate`, you'd have to jump through hoops (use regex) to do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3644621/5133585)